# How to set SetState after two Axios Calls?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-models, axios

I am probably doing this wrong but I need to make two Axios calls. One is to retrieve data from my database using Django, which stores API information and the other is to use that API key to call Google Calendar.

Both of the calls work, but the return of the response causes the setState not to set the value of the call from the Google Calendar. What is the best way to call a second call that is dependent on the first?

ComponentDidMount

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.getGCalCredentials();

};
```

getGCALCredentials:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    var url;
    const apiBaseUrl = "http://localhost:8000/";
    const payload = {
        "APIKey": this.state.APIKey,
        "CalendarID": this.state.CalendarID
    };
    axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    const localEvent = [];
     axios.get(apiBaseUrl + 'api/GetGCALCredentials/', payload, { headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'} }).then ( (response)  => {
        if (response.status == 200) {
            console.log("Successful. Credentials.");
            const d = JSON.parse(response.data);
            url = `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/` + d[0].fields.CalendarID + `/events?key=` + d[0].fields.APIKey + ``;
            this.setState({APIKey: d[0].fields.APIKey, CalendarID: d[0].fields.CalendarID});
            this.setState({url: url});
            console.log("[GCALCredentials] State is set:" + this.state.toString());
        }
        else if (response.status == 204) {
            console.log("Other Error");
            alert("username password do not match")
        }
        else if (response.status == 400) {
            console.log("Did not save successfully. ");
            alert("Did not save successfully. ")
        }
        else {
            console.log("Another error");
            alert("Some other Error.");
        }
        })
     .catch(function (error) {
            if (error.response.status==400){
                alert("Check your credentials at arlo.netgear.com. Invalid email or password. ");
                console.log("Data:" + error.response.data);
                console.log("Status: " + error.response.status);
                console.log("Headers: " + error.response.headers);
                console.log("Error: "+ error);
            }
     })
     .then(function(){
         axios.get(url)
          .then(function (resp) {
                resp.data.items.map((i) => {
                  const start = moment(i.start.dateTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').toDate();
                  const end = moment(i.start.dateTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').toDate();
                  localEvent.push({
                      fromDate: start,
                      toDate: end,
                      summary: i.summary,
                  });

              });
          })
          .then( (response) => {
              this.setState({events: localEvent});
              console.log("Google Calendar. State:" + this.state.toString());
         })
          .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
          });
      })
```

Comment: Wow that was fast for an edit.

Comment: You are never really calling `setState` after your second axios request are you?

Comment: I do this in componentDidMount.

Comment: Is this block:  `.then( (response) => {
              this.setState({events: localEvent});
              console.log("Google Calendar. State:" + this.state.toString());
         })` actually receiving a response object?

Comment: no. it is undef. but the localEvent array is populated.